# Clear Session Storage when Clicking Outside

Tags: session, meteor

I'm using Meteor and have the code below that stores _id into session:

```
 'click .players': function(){
      var playerId = this._id;
      Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerId);
```

The session above is set when user clicks within `<li class="players">`

I would like to clear the session data when user clicks outside of `<li class="players">`

What will be the best way to do this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is a little limited, because the selector `:not("li.players")` is within the template, which means that you may click somewhere outside the template and it will not fire a click event. It is advisable to put the click event under body template but it will still not fire a click event when you click the html part.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.events {
    'click :not("li.players")': function(e) {
      Session.set('selectedPlayer', null);
    }
  }
}
```

For more precisely, this might help you out.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  $(document).click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var target = $(e.target);
    var players = $('li.players');
    if (!players.is(target) && players.has(target).length === 0) {
      Session.set('selectedPlayer', null);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
'click :not(".players")': function(ev){
  Session.set('selectedPlayer',null);
}
```

[:not() css selector docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot)

Comment: the code only works when I click in certain areas outside of the `<li class="players">`lines.

How can I modify it so that the code clears session when i click _anywhere_ outside the `<li class="players">` area ?

Comment: Might need `'click body:not(".players")'`